# TypeOf undefined instead of comparing against undefined?

Tags: javascript, compatibility

In JavaScript, why would people write `typeof myVar == "undefined"` instead of `myVar == undefined`?

Is it for compatibility reasons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the main reason:

```
if(a == undefined) console.log('test')
>> ReferenceError: a is not defined
if(typeof a == "undefined") console.log('test')
>> test
```

But if you run this comparison:

```
if(window.a == undefined) console.log('test')
>> test
```

So if you use `a` as a standalone variable then you can't. Using `window` it's possible, and doesn't really matter what approach will you use, but as I stated in comment it's safer to use `typeof` as not every variable belongs to `window` scope.

Comment: Updated my answer - sorry for confusion.

Comment: Sorry - I seemed to be slightly rude with that comment.  Even then, doesn't make much difference in practice, does it?

Comment: Exactly - I don't think there is. But you can't always use `window` parent (global scope), because many variables exist in different scope, and are not properties of `window` object. And that's why `typeof` is best choice as it's working always.

Answer (score 1):

Because the typeof operator does not throw an Error if myVar is actually undefined.

```
myVar == undefined; // Throws a ReferenceError

typeof myVar == "undefined" //True
```